# Lowercase filter for 'Product List Name' in Google Analyitics

Tags: google-analytics

On my Google Analytics profile I have 2 filters, one which makes all my page URLs lowercase and another which makes all my search terms lowercase. They work fine on most reports, but when looking at Product List Performance I am seeing page names with uppercase as well as lowercase.

I've looked in the admin filters but I can't see a filter field for 'Product List Name' - is this something that can be done in admin, or do we have to make a code change to lowercase all product list pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, at this time, you can not create a filter that manipulates any product-level dimensions. The best course of action is to update the logic outputting the product list name to use a consistent convention.

For a list of supported filter fields, take a look at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034380?hl=en&ref_topic=1034830.